# type float4 in postgres truncates values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to insert values into a field in postgres.
The data type in that field is float4.
When I try to insert values into it, I get the value truncated as shown below

```
value: 18754999.99, pgAdmin truncates to 18755000
```

Please how can I prevent the truncation using float4 datatype

Comment: Use exact numeric types such as `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` to avoid this problem.

Comment: You can't.  Float4 doesn't support that value.

Answer (score 5):

`float4` a.k.a. `real` is stored in 4 bytes and has very limited precision. If you want more precision, use `float8` a.k.a. `double precision`. If you want no rounding errors at all, use `numeric`.